# How do I use a generic base class two levels down in an inheritance tree?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dto

Imagine that I have a generic base class like this:

```
public abstract class AnimalDTO<TA, TB>
{
    public static TB ToDTO(TA entity)
    {
        return ConvertToDTO<TB>(entity);
    }
}
```

The class is responsible for being able to convert a passed-in entity to a DTO.

I have a class that uses this generic class:

```
public class MammalDTO<Mammal, MammalDTO>
{
    // omitted stuff here
}
```

A user can now use `MammalDTO.ToDTO(mammal)` to convert a `Mammal` to a `MammalDTO`.

Now I want to derive off Mammal:

```
public class Koala<???, ???> : Mammal<???, ???>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to make`MammalDTO`an open but constrained generic type.
You could then try to constrain the generic further and further as you go down the inheritance hierarchy, closing it at a leaf. It may also be suitable to use abstract classes as appropriate, but this is not a requirement of the pattern.

To be honest though, I don't really like the 'self-referencing generic' pattern; I find it quite confusing.

```
public abstract class Animal { }
public abstract  class Mammal : Animal { }
public sealed class Koala : Mammal { }

public abstract class AnimalDTO<TAnimal, TDTO> where TAnimal : Animal
{
    public abstract TDTO ConvertToDTO(TAnimal entity);       
}

public abstract class MammalDTO<TMammal, TMammalDTO> : AnimalDTO<TMammal, TMammalDTO>
    where TMammal : Mammal
    where TMammalDTO : MammalDTO<TMammal, TMammalDTO>{}

public sealed class KoalaDTO : MammalDTO<Koala, KoalaDTO>
{
    public override KoalaDTO ConvertToDTO(Koala entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll try to find another way to do it, since I don't like this pattern either.